# Trigger para restar fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, tsql, sql-server-2014

Hola compañeros tengo esta consulta que funciona bien para encontrar la diferencia entre dos fechas en dias,horas, minutos y segundos pero al pasarlo al trigger ya no me funciona me sale un numero 4873 no se que estoy haciendo mal, mi columna diferencia es tipo varchar.

```
 select
    datediff(second, firstdate, lastdate),
    datediff(second, firstdate, lastdate) / 86400 as d,
    datediff(second, firstdate, lastdate) / 3600 as h,
    (datediff(second, firstdate, lastdate) % 3600) / 60 as m,
    (datediff(second, firstdate, lastdate) % 3600) % 60 as s
    from tiempos

5145    0   1   25  45
1695    0   0   28  15
4024    0   1   7   4

CREATE TRIGGER TGTIEMPOSRESTADEFECHAS
ON PRUEBAS 
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
UPDATE f
set f.diferencia = datediff(second, f.firstdate, f.lastdate)+
datediff(second, f.firstdate, f.lastdate) / 86400 +
datediff(second, f.firstdate, f.lastdate) / 3600 +
(datediff(second, f.firstdate, f.lastdate) % 3600) +
(datediff(second, f.firstdate, f.lastdate) % 3600) 
from inserted i inner join  Tiempos f on i.TestID=f.TestID
where f.diferencia is null end

2017-07-04 11:10:58.447 2017-07-04 12:18:02.930     4873
```

Comment: Estás sumando la diferencia en segundos, más la diferencia en días, más la diferencia en horas, etc. Qué resultado esperas?

Comment: lo mismo que al hacerlo solo como consulta 0   1   7   4 pero guardarlo en mi columna tiempo

Comment: pero lo que estás haciendo es sumando 0 + 1 + 7 + 4. Sería mucho mejor si pusieras el resultado que quieres obtener

Comment: Algo así  2017-07-04 11:10:58.447 2017-07-04 12:18:02.930  diferencia=0d,1h:7m:4s

Comment: qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lo que tú quieres es **concatenar** tus resultados, lo que es diferente a sumarlos:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGTIEMPOSRESTADEFECHAS
ON PRUEBAS 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    UPDATE f
    SET f.diferencia = CONCAT(DATEDIFF(SECOND,f.firstdate,f.lastdate)/86400,'d,',
                              DATEDIFF(SECOND,f.firstdate,f.lastdate)/3600,'h:',
                              (DATEDIFF(SECOND,f.firstdate,f.lastdate)%3600)/60,'m:',
                              (DATEDIFF(SECOND,f.firstdate,f.lastdate)%3600)%60,'s')
    FROM inserted i 
    INNER JOIN Tiempos f 
        ON i.TestID = f.TestID
    WHERE f.diferencia IS NULL;

END
```

Comment: gracias compañero funciono