# Suma de tiempos sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, trigger, datetime

Quiero hacer una consulta de triggers en SQL Server para lo siguiente:

Un campo calculado mi columna resta es la diferencia entre dos fechas y quiero que la columna total me haga la suma de esas diferencia mas la difrencia de la columna anterior por ejmplo los registros con calves c la primer diferencia fue 2 mas la segunda diferencia que fue  4 ahora serian 6

```
clave  resta   total
a      8         8
a      4         12
b      8         8
b      null      8


c      2         2
c      4         6
c      5         11


clave                                                    resta             total
a     2017-07-05 10:29:03.137   2017-07-05 10:34:23.283 0h:5m:20s     0h:5m:20s  

a     2017-07-05 10:34:23.283   2017-07-05 10:52:21.633 0h:19m:12s   0h:24m:32s  

a     2017-07-05 10:52:21.633   2017-07-05 10:53:35.027 0h:1m:51s     0h:25m:41s
```

Comment: No queda muy claro, puedes poner la columna de las fechas o algo asi?

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es acumular en `total` la suma de `resta` por cada `clave`?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta y puse un ejemplo, si eso es lo que quiero hacer el total de lo que lleva de la resta anterior por  cada clave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, y por las dudas que no lo tengas claro, es conveniente usar la diferencia en segundos entre ambas fechas (`resta`), por ejemplo así: `select datediff(s, <fechadesde>, <fechahasta>)`. Por lo que nuestro problema se va a basar en acumular los segundos. Hay mucha información en la red sobre este punto en particular, basta buscar por *"cumulative sum in sql server"* y verás que hay bastante escrito.

Como la suma acumulativa va a depender de un orden es conveniente disponer de un `ID` para cada registro para poder determinar el orden y además ya veremos que es necesario para la solución propuesta, en este ejemplo asumimos que ya lo tienes o lo has creado, por otro lado vamos a usar los mismos valores de `resta` de tu ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Ejemplo TABLE (
    id      INT IDENTITY,
    clave   CHAR(1),
    resta   INT
)

INSERT INTO @Ejemplo (clave, resta)
VALUES ('a', 8), ('a', 4), ('b', 8), ('b', NULL), ('c', 2), ('c', 4), ('c', 5)
```

Con esto tendremos una tabla `@Ejemplo`con los datos de tu pregunta. Una opción para acumular la suma que es bastante compatible entre versiones se SQL Server, es la siguiente:

```
SELECT  t1.clave, 
    t1.resta, 
    SUM(t2.resta) AS 'Total'
    FROM @Ejemplo t1
    INNER JOIN @Ejemplo t2 
        ON t1.id >= t2.id
        AND t1.clave = t2.clave
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.clave, t1.resta
    ORDER BY t1.id
```

Aquí se ve el uso del `id`, lo usamos para ir sumando los valores anteriores y actuales de cada fila. La salida obtenida:

```
clave resta Total
===== ===== =====
a     8,00  8,00
a     4,00  12,00
b     8,00  8,00
b     NULL  8,00
c     2,00  2,00
c     4,00  6,00
c     5,00  11,00
```

Otra solución es usar `OVER PARTITION` pero esto aplica a partir de SQL 2008

```
SELECT  t.clave, 
        t.resta, 
        SUM(t.resta) OVER (PARTITION BY clave order by id) as 'Total'
        FROM ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY clave) AS 'id',
                        clave, 
                        resta
                        FROM @Ejemplo
             ) T
```

De paso obviamos la necesidad del `id` usando el `ROW_NUMBER()` pero de todas formas no te lo recomiendo, es preferible tener un campo que sirva efectivamente para ordenar los resultados, de manera que la consulta siempre devuelva el mismo orden. Entiendo que sabes luego como transformar los segundos en el formato que solicitas, sino te recomiendo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83894/trigger-para-restar-fechas) muy actual.

Comment: Compañero y como le puedo hacer para que directo de la columna resta me de los resultados en segundos porque ahorita esa columna es char

Comment: En este caso, tienes que ir un paso adelante, y como te decía al principio, calcular la diferencia en segundos, por lo dices ahora, `resta` ya la tienes convertida en un `varchar` o similar, por lo que deberías tener un `resta_segundos` dónde guardes directamente los segundos mediante `datediff(s, <fechadesde>, <fechahasta>)`, luego la suma acumulada la trabajes sobre este campo, por último  conviertas el mismo a `varchar` con el formato que estas manejando. Te sugiero, para no hacer interminables los comentarios, que si tienes alguna duda adicional la evacues mediante otra pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puede quedar así

```
SELECT 
 id AS id_prim,
 clave, resta AS,
 (SELECT SUM(resta)
   FROM tu_tabla 
   WHERE id <=  id_prim
 ) AS total
 FROM tu_tabla
```

Es importante agregar el id a la consulta para ver hasta donde iterar